# Does a C# Bitmap remember where it came from?

Tags: c#, winforms

This question is specific to [System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx).

Consider this situation: I create a bitmap like so

```
public Bitmap GetImage(string sourceImage) 
{
   //sourceImage contains something like "C:\\Users\\my.name\\path\\to\\image.jpg"
   //error/valid filename checking omitted in this example
   Bitmap img = new Bitmap(sourceImage);
   return img;
}
```

Now my code goes and does things with that `Bitmap`.  Later, an unrelated section of the code decides that it is done with that image and it doesn't need to retain the `Bitmap` object anymore.  However, there is a chance that it will be needed again, so it wants to remember what `sourceImage` was so that if it does need it again, it knows how to recreate it.  This is mostly due to memory; storing a pathway string takes less space than storing a (potentially) large image.

**Does a `Bitmap` remember where it came from, or must it carry around that information with it?**

I considered just assigning `sourceImage` to the `Tag` property, however I'm using `Tag` for other things and I'd rather not overcomplicate it.  I'm hoping the source information is still accessible to save me the trouble.

Comment: no - https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Image.cs,b2315d1ff08bc616 and annoyingly the class is sealed so you cant create a derived class with the the ImagePath as an attribute

Comment: Why not use Tag though? Make your own class and put an instance of that in there, sounds like that's exactly what you want.

Comment: @DavidG I'm using Tag to carry some other information around.  If I do modify it to also carry around more information, the resulting refactor will be a fair amount of trouble.  I'm hoping to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: Then you need to pass the image reference along with the sourceImage value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend creating a container class to provide the extra functionality

```
class BitmapContainer : IDisposable
{
    Bitmap Value {get; private set;}
    string OriginalLocation {get; private set;}

    public BitmapContainer(string sourceImage) 
    {
        Value = new Bitmap(sourceImage);
        OriginalLocation = sourceImage;
        //you get the picture
    }

    //Don't forget to implement a dispose pattern because Bitmap uses native resources
}
```

You could even make the bitmap getter intelligent and load the Bitmap if not currently loaded, and have another method for unloading (Dispose and set to null) until needed again